# libgcov fork and exec hooks

Tags: c, linux, gcc, gcov

My man page for gcc claims about the `--coverage` option:

> Also "fork" calls are detected and correctly handled (double counting will not happen).

And I notice my /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/libgcov.a contains symbols `__gcov_fork`, `__gcov_execl`, and other `__gcov_exec*` variants.  Looking up the definitions of these functions online, it looks like they would dump and clear coverage output to avoid duplicating or losing the data.

But this doesn't seem to be working for me:

```
gcov_test$ rm *.gcno *.gcda
gcov_test$ cat gcov_test.c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(void) {
    puts("Before loop");
    for (int i=0; i<5; ++i)
        printf("i=%d\n", i);
    puts("After loop");
    pid_t child1 = fork();
    if (child1<0) {
        perror("fork 1");
        exit(1);
    } else if (child1==0) {
        printf("In child 1: %d\n", (int)getpid());
        execl("/bin/true", "/bin/true", (char*)NULL);
        perror("execl");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Parent spawned child 1: %d\n", (int)child1);
    pid_t child2 = fork();
    if (child2<0)
    {
        perror("fork 2");
        exit(1);
    } else if (child2==0) {
        printf("In child 2: %d\n", (int)getpid());
    } else {
        printf("Parent spawned child 2: %d\n", (int)child2);
        if (waitpid(child1, NULL, 0)<0)
            perror("waitpid 1");
        if (waitpid(child2, NULL, 0)<0)
            perror("waitpid 2");
        puts("Parent done");
    }
    return 0;
}

gcov_test$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

gcov_test$ gcc -c -std=c11 -Wall --coverage gcov_test.c 
gcov_test$ gcc --coverage gcov_test.o -o gcov_test
gcov_test$ ./gcov_test
Before loop
i=0
i=1
i=2
i=3
i=4
After loop
Parent spawned child 1: 31569
Parent spawned child 2: 31570
In child 2: 31570
In child 1: 31569
Parent done
gcov_test$ gcov gcov_test.c
File 'gcov_test.c'
Lines executed:64.29% of 28
Creating 'gcov_test.c.gcov'

gcov_test$ cat gcov_test.c.gcov
        -:    0:Source:gcov_test.c
        -:    0:Graph:gcov_test.gcno
        -:    0:Data:gcov_test.gcda
        -:    0:Runs:2
        -:    0:Programs:1
        -:    1:#include <stdlib.h>
        -:    2:#include <stdio.h>
        -:    3:#include <unistd.h>
        -:    4:#include <sys/types.h>
        -:    5:#include <sys/wait.h>
        -:    6:
        2:    7:int main(void) {
        2:    8:    puts("Before loop");
       12:    9:    for (int i=0; i<5; ++i)
       10:   10:        printf("i=%d\n", i);
        2:   11:    puts("After loop");
        2:   12:    pid_t child1 = fork();
        2:   13:    if (child1<0) {
    #####:   14:        perror("fork 1");
    #####:   15:        exit(1);
        2:   16:    } else if (child1==0) {
    #####:   17:        printf("In child 1: %d\n", (int)getpid());
    #####:   18:        execl("/bin/true", "/bin/true", (char*)NULL);
    #####:   19:        perror("execl");
    #####:   20:        exit(1);
        -:   21:    }
        2:   22:    printf("Parent spawned child 1: %d\n", (int)child1);
        2:   23:    pid_t child2 = fork();
        2:   24:    if (child2<0)
        -:   25:    {
    #####:   26:        perror("fork 2");
    #####:   27:        exit(1);
        2:   28:    } else if (child2==0) {
        1:   29:        printf("In child 2: %d\n", (int)getpid());
        -:   30:    } else {
        1:   31:        printf("Parent spawned child 2: %d\n", (int)child2);
        1:   32:        if (waitpid(child1, NULL, 0)<0)
    #####:   33:            perror("waitpid 1");
        1:   34:        if (waitpid(child2, NULL, 0)<0)
    #####:   35:            perror("waitpid 2");
        1:   36:        puts("Parent done");
        -:   37:    }
        2:   38:    return 0;
        -:   39:}
        -:   40:
gcov_test$
```

It looks to me like the "child 1" process never wrote its coverage results to file, since in particular the `"In child 1"` line executed but is not shown as covered.  And all the lines before the second `fork` seem to report doubled coverage, so it seems the coverage results were not reset at calling `fork` as the man page claimed.

Is there something else I need to do to enable those libgcov hooks?  I'm not supposed to actually replace the syscalls with the actual hook names just when compiling in coverage mode, am I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution: replace `c11` with `gnu11`.

`-std=c11` means pure C11 (without GNU extensions). `-std=gnu11` also enables GNU extensions. I can't explain the connection between `-std=` and `--coverage` (probably `-std=` affects built-in function usage in general, and `__gcov_fork` is one of them), but simply changing the standard to `gnu11` seems to solve the problem, i.e., both line 17 and 29 now have execution count equal to 1. (I tried it both on GCC 5.4.0 and a recent trunk revision).

P.S. I suggest you to file a bug report. Even if this behavior is intended, the compiler should at least warn us about potential problems.

Comment: Fix: `__gcov_fork` is not a built-in function. `exec*` and `fork` are.

Comment: There is a bug report about this: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla//show_bug.cgi?id=82457.  The behaviour is apparently intentional, since with `-std=c11`, GCC doesn't assume it knows what POSIX functions do.