How can I generate coverage for program which ends in an execve()?
How can I generate usable coverage reports for a program that ends with execve() instead of exit() or a similar function? The second program that is being execve()d is irrelevant for the coverage report (it is an user supplied program, it could be anything, a Python script, program build without coverage instrumentation etc.). I have tried generating coverage using both gcc and clang and the relevant coverage files either don't get generated or say that no line of code was executed (which is false).

Not sure if it's still relevant, but please see "How to force gcov to extract data, even when program is aborted".

Did you try calling __gcov_dump() before the execve?

Since you seem to be interested only in coverage, why not just replace the execve by exit?

Could you force execve to return an error and then exit afterwards? This will also cover your execve failure handling code. :-)

@IanAbbott If I have to modify the code to make coverage feasible, than I won't be gathering coverage for my program, would I? I would be gathering coverage for a different, but very similar program. If coverage imposes such strict requirements on program termination, than it must be completely unusable for many projects, correct? I have assumed that coverage should be "transparent" and shouldn't require codebase modification, like ASAN. My code is correct as it is. I do not wish to modify it because some external tool doesn't like my correct code.

That's like rewriting correct code because the target compiler has a bug and is nonconforming to the standard. This isn't the code's fault, but the compiler's (or here gcov's or llvm's).

I'm not sure if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46381406 is relevant to your problem or not, as that question is a few years old.

A program (a process) that executes an execve() is not a terminating process.  It is just a process that loads and starts a new program in the same execution context that was present before the exec() system call took place.
When a process exec()s, it just closes all close on exec file descriptors, and reloads a new program instead of the one executing before.  From the system view, nothing else happened.  The process continues accumulating CPU time... al open (and not close on exec) descriptors continue to be accessible (but probably the new program will be unaware of this fact, because there are no variables holding their values) and no ending program is to be seen (no exiting process, nor new process creation takes place)
The only way to create a new process is to execute fork() while the only way to end a process is by signalling it, or because the process called exit() system call.
Coverage will be applied if the new program has also been compiled with coverage support.  Anyway, probably you will be messing the coverage info, as it took place with the coverage info of the previous command, while the new program can have completely different coverage info.
IMHO you have no clear idea about the coverage info, if you plan to cross coverage information over an exec() system call.  You will start accumulating coverage info with the new set of counters, but in a different program (this is what requires you to have also the new program to be compiled with coverage support)

Thank you for your answer! I am not exactly sure how are the first three paragraphs relevant to my question. You are correct, that is how these syscalls work, but I am not questioning that. I am only interested in my program's coverage, not the executed one's. As outlined on my original question, the executed program may be anything, it could be for example a Python or Bash script. I can't build a Bash or Python script with coverage info. Even if I built the interpreters with coverage info, it would be useless.

Your program coverage depends on the coverage info generated when compiling the code.  You have changed all the code, and it is possible that the coverage info (number and addresses of the pointers that will collect the info) when executing the system call. If you can still do something, for sure it will be in a completely different coverage context.
